# rbenv continually generating vagrant shim

Tags: ruby, vagrant, rbenv

I am using the latest vagrant with rbenv and various rubies.

I am using the latest vagrant, which no longer uses a gem. When I execute a vagrant command I see the following error:

```
rbenv: vagrant: command not found
```

I have removed the old vagrant gem from all ruby environments BUT everytime I "cd" the vagrant shim is regenerated, meaning vagrant stops working until I rm the shim manually:

```
rm /home/{user}/.rbenv/shims/vagrant
```

Is there a way to force rbenv to stop this behaviour?

rbenv plugins in use":

- ruby-build
- rbenv-gemset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until this issue is resolved in rbenv, you could do this:

```
alias vagrant /full/path/to/vagrant
```

Then everytime you run vagrant, the actual vagrant binary will be executed, rather than the shim.

Comment: You can also put this in `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc`) to make this the default.

Comment: Should of thought of that one. Delightfully lazy.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`ls ~/.rbenv/versions/*/bin | grep 'vagrant'`

and if have gemset plugin

`ls ~/.rbenv/*/gemsets/*/bin/ | grep 'vagrant'`

If commands return results, delete the files. After this run `rbenv rehash`.

Comment: have others plugin installed?

Comment: only ruby-build and rbenv-gemset

Comment: Strange, shims are build with `rehash` only from bin presents in versions/*/bin.

Answer (score 3):

Other people have apparently had the same problem; see https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/388.

If you are using [the bundler plugin](https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler) for rbenv, then vendoring a project which uses the vagrant gem will evidently cause the shim to be built; try removing the bundler plugin, remove the vagrant shim, and run `rbenv rehash` to see the problem is fixed.

If you aren't using the bundler plugin, can you give us a list of all the rbenv plugins you are using?

Comment: Had a similar issue with `docker`. The issue thread referenced above (#388) solved it for me. It was the `~/.rbenv/bundles` file that referenced a project on my system which contained a `bin/docker` binary... After `rm ~/.rbenv/bundles && rbenv rehash` the stale `docker` shim finally did not reappear.