# bash alias to rbenv shim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, terminal

I'm trying set up a simple bash alias:

```
alias b="bundle"
```

when I look at the alias in bash I get:

```
alias b='"bundle"'
```

which makes a mess of following aliases.

I think this is due to it pointing to the rbenv shim `bundle` in $PATH but I could be wrong.

Any pointers for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can look at

```
~/.bashrc
```

and correct it...

try to define it like(in terminal or ~/bashrc):

```
alias b='bundle'
```

Also have look [HERE1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394338/how-do-rvm-and-rbenv-actually-work) and [HERE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496333/rbenv-continually-generating-vagrant-shim) and [HERE3](https://github.com/christopherwright/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc)

Comment: thanks for the ideas. It is correctly defined in ~/.bashrc: alias b='bundle' shows up as alias b=' 'bundle' ' in terminal, I still can't see why the extra ' are showing up.  So b="bundle" in ~/.bashrc looks like b=" 'bundle' " in terminal (added extra spaces for clarity).

Comment: also `alias b="bundle"` is correct... Really I don't know..so strange...try this one `alias b=bundle`

Comment: alias b=bundle looks like b='bundle' in terminal which is fine.  However I want to define bu='bundle update' and this turns out as: bu=' 'bundle' ' update' in terminal and fails (of course).

Comment: how about : `alias bu=bundle\ \update` or `alias bu=bundle\ update`

Comment: I think the main problem is about your bash on terminal configurations...It is manipulated... try to solve it...(if you get answer don't forget to tick)

Comment: Yes.  Escaping them seems to work, I can solve it this way, but it's odd.  Thanks for the help.